# Reported width of "auto" span is greater than actual, rendered width

Tags: jquery, dom, rangy, pdf.js

I'm using [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to create a highlight for a selection for text that has been rendered using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). The CSS for the highlighted `span` is very simple:

```
.image-highlight {
    background-color: rgba(152, 210, 146, 0.45);
    border: 1px solid #000000; //added this for debugging.
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Since successive highlights in rangy are dependent on the previous highlights, I'm trying to copy the height and width of the `span` that is created by rangy and then place it in another root node. However, I'm noticing that the width of the newly-created `span` is greater than the original `span`. What is also frustrating is that Chrome reports the same width for both `span`s in `px`, even though they are obviously different!

The width for the first `span` (created by rangy) has a width of `auto` as reported by Chrome when viewed under `Metrics` in the developer toolbar, whereas the width for the second span (that I create) is explicitly set via `$.width`.

Here is how I am copying the `span` over:

```
var $selectionSpan = jQuery("<span></span>").
    attr("id", "created-" + new Date().getTime()).
    css("position", "absolute").
    css("z-index", 999).
    offset({
        top: $span.offset().top,
        left: $span.offset().left
    }).
    height($span.height()).
    width($span.width());

$selectionSpan.get(0).className = $span.get(0).className;
```

And here are pictures of Chrome reporting that the width is the same for both `span`s:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the width is being reported as `112px` even though they are obviously different. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. This was due to pdf.js applying a CSS3 scale-transformation. I would expect Chrome to report the transformed width and not the un-transformed width, but I guess that might be a Chrome bug.

I was able to fix this by appending the following to the code that creates my `span`:

```
css("-webkit-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-webkit-transform")).
css("-moz-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-moz-transform")).
css("-ms-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-ms-transform")).
css("-o-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-o-transform")).
css("-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-transform")).
css("-webkit-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-webkit-transform-origin")).
css("-moz-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-moz-transform-origin")).
css("-ms-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-ms-transform-origin")).
css("-o-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-o-transform-origin")).
css("-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-transform-origin"));
```

So the complete code looks like this:

```
var $selectionSpan = jQuery("<span></span>").
    attr("id", "created-" + new Date().getTime()).
    css("position", "absolute").
    css("z-index", 999).
    offset({
        top: $span.offset().top,
        left: $span.offset().left
    }).
    height($span.height()).
    width($span.width()).
    css("-webkit-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-webkit-transform")).
    css("-moz-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-moz-transform")).
    css("-ms-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-ms-transform")).
    css("-o-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-o-transform")).
    css("-transform", $span.parent("div").css("-transform")).
    css("-webkit-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-webkit-transform-origin")).
    css("-moz-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-moz-transform-origin")).
    css("-ms-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-ms-transform-origin")).
    css("-o-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-o-transform-origin")).
    css("-transform-origin", $span.parent("div").css("-transform-origin"));
```